# ClassNotFound: ComboPooledDataSource, followed by JasperException: /struts-tags is missing

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, struts2

I've been thrown into a project with Spring/Struts/Hibernate etc. already set up through Maven for me. I have no prior knowledge of any of these technologies, just learning as I go and I'm using Eclipse.

Today I started working on Solr (the library was already a maven dependency), ran the code in a class with a main method and made sure it was working correctly,  before incorporating the Solr stuff the correct way (Command Pattern).

Thing is that once I did this, I started getting this:

> ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource'

I don't have the full trace because I didn't think of saving it and I can't replicate it anymore. This is my datasource.xml for which it complained the class was missing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- connection pool implementation c3p0 http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0 --> 
    <bean id="dataSource"
    class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${datasource.url}"/>
        <property name="user" value="${datasource.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${datasource.password}"/>
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="3"/>
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="3"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="3"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="150"/>
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true"/>
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="300"/>
        <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="select 1"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

The class was definitely in the Maven Dependencies though. I couldn't figure out the error so I reverted back to a working version on git. And now I'm getting the following output when starting the server:

```
Aug 30, 2016 4:03:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal                 performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program     Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Interwoven\WorkSite\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Philips Speech Shared\Components;C:\Program Files (x86)\Enterprise Vault\EVClient\;C:\Program Files (x86)\WebEx\Productivity Tools;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;"C:\typesafe-activator-1.3.10\activator-dist-1.3.10\bin";"C:\Programs\sbt\bin";C:\Programs\eclipse;;.
Aug 30, 2016 4:03:46 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Aug 30, 2016 4:03:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 500 ms
Aug 30, 2016 4:03:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 30, 2016 4:03:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.45
Aug 30, 2016 4:03:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor com.pinsentmasons.clauseextract.web.xml
Aug 30, 2016 4:03:47 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Aug 30, 2016 4:03:47 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Aug 30, 2016 4:03:47 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/15  config=null
Aug 30, 2016 4:03:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 304 ms
```

Now when I load up the web page I get the following:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp(2,41) File "/struts-tags" not found
    at             org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
    at       org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:163)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:450)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1400)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:130)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:255)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:103)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:185)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:612)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:503)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This version of the code was working completely fine when it was committed, so I can assume that the code isn't at fault anymore. I have tried cleaning the project and doing a Maven update to no avail. I'm quite lost.

Comment: If you can't replicate it why are you asking the question? In any case, there's nothing here anybody can use to help. Make sure you're deploying correctly?

Comment: Because I was completely lost as to how code that was working perfectly could break like that and was hoping someone had some idea as to what I could do. I managed to fix it by cleaning the Tomcat server and republishing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the problem had nothing to do with the classes or even my own code, but it was a problem with Tomcat.

I was cleaning the project and doing an Update Project through Maven, however I hadn't cleaned the Tomcat server, once I cleaned and republished the project everything was back to working state.